# How can I solve this Video Playback Problem In Xubuntu 16.10

Tags: xubuntu, video, vlc

I just did a clean install of Xubuntu 16.10 from Ubuntu Main 16.04 (including formatting my /home partition.)

Since then I'm finding that I can't play HD 1080p x264 mkv files any more. Basically they freeze VLC & cause serious jumping in Parole & MPV Media Player.

I didn't have this problem in Ubuntu Main 16.04 - I can't play files I played fine then.

I have tried changing VLC settings such as file cache to no avail. If I run VLC from the terminal I get

> [h264 @ 0x7f3358ce0420] error while decoding MB 54 29, bytestream -7
>
> [00007f3358c019b8] mkv demux error: Dummy Element at unexpected position... corrupted file?
>
> [00007f3358c019b8] mkv demux error: Dummy element too large or misplaced at 115569287... skipping to next upper element
>
> [00007f3358c019b8] mkv demux error: This element is outside its known parent... upping level

Here are some laptop specs

> Processor     : 2x Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU B815 @ 1.60GHz
> Memory         : 3895MB (1349MB used)
>
> Operating System   : Ubuntu 16.10 (Xubuntu)
>
> Kernel: Linux 4.8.0-41-generic, Architecture: x86-64
>
> -Display-
>
> Resolution     : 1366x768 pixels
>
> OpenGL Renderer        : Mesa DRI Intel(R) Sandybridge Mobile
>
> X11 Vendor     : The X.Org Foundation
>
> -Multimedia-
>
> Audio Adapter      : HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH

Any suggestions?

Many thanks,
Barry

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have solved this problem by installing an alternative compositor called Compton.

I used the instructions here, but NB the PPA he uses no longer has the package. Not hard to find though.

http://duncanlock.net/blog/2013/06/07/how-to-switch-to-compton-for-beautiful-tear-free-compositing-in-xfce/